# Animation is not working in RecyclerView in NestedScrollView in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using two RecyclerView in LinearLayout in NestedScrollView see xml file.

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvData1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvData2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And i wrote the code animation in onBindViewHolder Adapter class

```
            holder.parentView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.right_to_left));
```

And My all code is perfect when i deleted code NestedScrollView then animation is perfect working and NestedScrollView visible then it is not working animation like simple to display all items in row of adapter.

Android guys share your best experience what you did.
Thank You !

Comment: Did you try disabling the nested scroll before setting the animation? And is that your current and final XML? Why are you using a LinearLayout as parent of the RV?

Comment: i am using 3 rv in linear layout and parent Nested Scroll that's way. Animation is not working in nestedscoll. if you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: NestedScrollView supports multiple childs, so you could have the 3 RVs directly put inside the NestedScrollView, no need for the LinearLayout. That strategy is used when you're using ScrollView which supports only one child. Change that because this could cause trouble in your animations

Comment: @AgustinMagne issue about NestedScrollView not a linear layout and animation is not working inside nestedsv and if i disabled nestedsv then it works. thanks to support and try to other one plz.

Comment: It was just a suggestion because Animations can be tricky and a bad layout hierarchy can mess things up, it certainly did for me a few times. Good luck with your problem mate.

Comment: my requirement is different things and i want animation.

Answer (score 0):

> Change your coding style, can you make nested recyclerview, I mean, In
> one recyclerview put rest of recyclerview. you can create this kind of
> recyclerview by using VIEW_TYPE

Comment: okay. can u give me one example which is exactly code what u said?

Comment: You can use [`MergeAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter) to achieve this effect easily without rewriting your adapters.